# Can I detect if chrome is in Windows 8 (metro) mode

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

Is there a way to detect if Google chrome is running in Windows 8 (metro) mode or in Desktop mode?

I am writing a Chrome extension and I don't want it to run in Metro mode.